# How to show that the set of functions $E=\{f(0)=f(1)=0\}$ is closed in $C[0, 1]$ with respect to the $\infty$ norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

To do it I need to show that all limit points of $E$ are inside $C[0, 1]$. How can it be showed?
One option is to show that addition of $E$ is an open set.
The second is to build some sequence which has a limit in $E$, I think.
But how can it be done correctly?

The first steps of my solution using the second option, so we need to prove that $E$ contains all its limit points:

1) Using the theorem: $f_0(x)$ is a limit point of the set $E \subset C[0, 1] \iff \exists \{f_n\} \subset E: f_n \to f_0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $f_n \neq f_0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb N $.

2) Now we need to show that $f_0 \in E$. And here I've stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n(0) =0$ and $f_n(1)=0$. You know that $f_n \to f_0$, where $f_0 \in C([0,1])$ and the symbol $\to$ means convergence in supermum norm.

You have to prove that $f_0 (0) =f_0(1) =0$. This follows from the fact that $f_n \to f_0$. Can you explain why?

Comment: I would add for completeness that $\to$ means converges in supremum norm.

Comment: Your are right, now it is more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Hermione Am I right that since $max_{x \in [0, 1]}|f_n(x) - f_0(x)| < \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\Rightarrow$ if x = 0 then $|f_0(0)| < \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_0(0) = 0$. Analogically for x = 1. Therefore $f_0(0) = f_0(1) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_0 \in E$. So E is a closed set.

Comment: Yes @shpindler, you are right

Comment: @Hermione, thanks!